# Запрос с несколькими условиями БД Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, ms-access

Имею таблицы Продуктов, Блюд и Состав блюд.
Мне нужно при добавлении блюда в корзину убрать то количество продуктов, которое указано в таблице "Состав блюда"
У меня получился запрос только с удалением фиксированного количества продуктов, равным в данном случае единице
Хорошо работает, но мне нужно изменить эту единичку на значение поля "Количество" в таблице "Состав блюда", где Код блюда = order id

```
"UPDATE [Продукты] SET [Количество] = [Количество] - 1 WHERE [Код продукта] IN (SELECT[Код продукта] FROM [Состав блюда] WHERE [Код блюда] = " + order.id + ")";
```

Не подскажете, как это можно сделать? Приведу код моей попытки

```
"UPDATE [Продукты] SET [Количество] = ([Количество] - (SELECT [Количество] FROM [Состав блюда] WHERE [Код блюда] = " + order.id + " AND [Код продукта] IN (SELECT[Код продукта] FROM [Состав блюда] WHERE [Код блюда] = " + order.id + ")))";
```

При выполнении этого запроса появляется ошибка
Код

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос."

Большое спасибо за прочтение! [image]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением класса с полями Код продукта и количество блюда в составе, после чего создал List из класса и работал с ним

Это самый лучший вариант?

Answer (score 0):

@Gregory вообще немного непонятно. 
Есть таблица [Продукты], которая не указана в списке таблиц. (Предполагаю, что в данной таблице хранится поле [Количество].

Чтобы сделать всё одним запросом - используйте:

```
$q1 = "UPDATE [Продукты] SET [Количество] = [Количество] - (SELECT [Количество] FROM [Состав блюда] WHERE [Код продукта] = " + order.id + ") WHERE [Код продукта] IN (SELECT [Код продукта] FROM [Состав блюда] WHERE [Код блюда] = " + order.id + ")";
```

Вычитает из поля [Количество] в таблице [Продукты], где код продукта - равен коду продукта из таблицы [Состав блюда] , в котором [Код блюда] = order.id, именно то количество продуктов, которое указано в таблице [Состав блюда] c указанным [Код блюда] = order.id